# Exception when run my program in another machine

Tags: vb.net

Any idea for this error message? I hit this error when i run my program in another machine!

[image]

Comment: Visual Basic Power pack not installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using some components that are not part of the stock .Net Runtime (namely, the [Visual Basic Power Pack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb735936.aspx)) and so need to distribute those components with your app.